# Enable virtualization on Lenovo AMD Ryzen 5 so I can install WSL2 on Windows VM on host Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a Windows 10 VM on Virtualbox running on host Ubuntu 22.04.
I want WSL2 on the VM Windows just for the terminal as I don't like Cmd and Powershell compared to Bash.
I tried following WSL install steps, it looks like it installs but then upon opening a bash tab from Windows terminal get:

```
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370102
Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.For information please visit https://aka.ms/enablevirtualization
Press any key to continue...

[process exited with code 1 (0x00000001)]
```

It says

"Error: 0x80370102 The virtual machine could not be started because a required feature is not installed."

Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.

```
Check the Hyper-V system requirements

If your machine is a VM, please enable nested virtualization manually. Launch powershell with admin, and run:
PowerShell
```

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-VMProcessor -VMName Windows10 -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true
Set-VMProcessor : The term 'Set-VMProcessor' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-VMProcessor -VMName Windows10 -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $tr ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Set-VMProcessor:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting#error-0x80370102-the-virtual-machine-could-not-be-started-because-a-required-feature-is-not-installed

The name I see in the Virtualbox GUI is Windows10.  Is this wrong?

Also I am running that command in Powershell in Admin mode in my VM.

Do I need to run something in host Ubuntu 22?

I already went into Bios and saw that AMD-V virtualization setting was enabled.

What else can I try?

Screenshot requested in comments:

[image: windows features]

Comment: You need to enable Virtual Machine Platform. Show us a screenshot of the optional Windows features you currently have installed. The commands you ran are only appropriate for Hyper-V VMs not VirtualBox VMs and they have to be ran on the host not the VM itself

Comment: I am 90% sure the reason you can’t enable nested virtualization is because either AND doesn’t support it because Hyper-V does supports it on the OS you are on or you haven’t enabled it within the configuration of your VirtualBox VM

Comment: I see, I am going to try these in host Ubuntu:https://ostechnix.com/how-to-enable-nested-virtualization-in-virtualbox/

Comment: I even tried this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v and still getting same errors although Powershell tells me, `PS C:\Users\nobut> wsl.exe --install Ubuntu-20.04
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is already installed.
Launching Ubuntu 20.04 LTS...`

Comment: That command only works if it’s not already installed. Provide that screenshot by editing your question. Also provide screenshots of your VirtualBox configuration

Comment: Nested virtualization often does not support using a different hypervisor inside the VM. You'd have Hyper-V inside VirtualBox.

Comment: @Ramhound what screenshots should I post?

Comment: @DanielB is there a workaround?

Comment: Don’t use WSL 2, especially if all you want is Bash.